# How to recursively print the contents of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I want to have a function that takes in a `template` for a `std::vector` and prints whatever is in the vector provided it is a datatype allowed in `std::cout`. I believe this needs to be recursive since what about a **vector of vector of a vector...**. For example, given a 1d `vector`,

```
template< typename T>
void PrintVector(T vec)
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
       std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

There are a few problems I have here with this code.

**1.** This doesn't work if it is a multi-dimensional vector, I need it to (I guess at this statement: `vec[i]`) recursively go and print out that vector and do the same if there is another vector.

**2.** I also want it to take in a reference to the vector within the template so I don't copy a 3d vector that's like 1gb in size to print it, rather just reference so I don't allocate any memory to do so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: regarding 2.: what is the problem? What is stopping you from taking it by reference?

Comment: @bolov I don't know how. Also the other issue is i'm not even sure if that syntax is correct. I need it to take in an `std::vector< TEMPLATE >` instead of a template anyway.

Comment: then it's time to start with a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I've just noticed you edited your post to ask a completely different question. Don't do that! Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @bolov I can't. Reached my question limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's clarify some things: `std::vector` is a template, but `std::vector<T>` is a class (generated from the template, but that is irrelevant). Also the `T` in the `std::vector<T>` is a type not a template.

> I also want it to take in a reference to the vector within the template

It doesn't work like that. You simply make the function parameter a reference.

Coming back to your main question. One common way to do this is with an overloaded function:

```
template <class T>
void print(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << obj;
}

template <class T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (const auto& elem : v)
    {
        print(elem);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When you call `print` with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` the 2nd overload is chosen because it matches and is more specialized than the 1st. `T` is deduced to be `std::vector<int>`; `print(elem)` calls 2nd overload with `T` deduced as `int` and here `print(elem)` calls the 1st overload.

Comment: So its recursively printing the vector but with a different overloaded function of the same name? Also, what type would you replace `elem` with if you didn't use auto? I am just wondering if say I want to do a traditional for loop with a counter

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { print(v[i]); }`